# XSLT 1.0: rename duplicate elements with same content using counter

Tags: xml, xslt

I referred to an old thread of mine because I have a similar problem to this one:
[XSLT 1.0: rename elements with same content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875221/xslt-1-0-rename-elements-with-same-content)

I have the following XML source. Within each `Item` Element I have children that could have the same value, for example in the 3rd `Item` I have two children with values "ZA SOUTH AFRICA" and "SPAR WC".
These I have to "make unique" with a suffix, for example a counter number.

This is the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntityGroup>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000004644</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>CHECKERS</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>OK KZN</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5/>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000004612</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5/>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000056016</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000056020</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>SUPERSPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
</EntityGroup>
```

I came up with this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <Item>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="number">
                <xsl:number/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item/child::*">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'-',count(preceding-sibling::*[. = current()]))"/>   
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntityGroup>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000004644-0</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>CHECKERS-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>OK KZN-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000004612-0</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000056016-0</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA SOUTH AFRICA-1</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>SPAR WC-1</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000056020-0</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>SUPERSPAR WC-0</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
</EntityGroup>
```

But I am expecting this output - please pay attention to the 3rd `Item` element. I only
want duplicate values within `Item` elements to be with a suffix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntityGroup>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000004644</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>CHECKERS</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>OK KZN</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5/>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000004612</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5/>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000056016</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA SOUTH AFRICA-1</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>SPAR WC-1</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>0000056020</ENTITY_GROUP_CODE>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>ZA SOUTH AFRICA</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL1>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>ZA GROCERY</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL2>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>SPAR</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL3>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>SPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL4>
    <ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>SUPERSPAR WC</ENTITY_GROUP_LEVEL5>
</Item>
</EntityGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost you are near the results, just change as given:

```
<xsl:template match="Item/child::*">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[. = current()] and not(current()='')">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'-',count(preceding-sibling::*[. = current()]))"/>   
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you Rudramuni, it works well. I only added "<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[. = current()] and not(current()='')">" to check on empty elements. For empties the logic must not be applied. Best regards,

Comment: Welcome Peter, nice logical code u coded, now it will be complete one. I edited my answer.